# SharePoint Word Template central repository

Tags: templates, sharepoint, ms-word, save

I have to build something like this:

All our Word templates are saved in a central SharePoint Site (Document Library). For every customer we have a dedicated sharepoint workspace. In the workspace there should be a view, webpart or something like this where the all the files from the central template library should be shown. The template files should not lay NOT in the customer workspace.

When an user clicks on a word template in this view, webpart, the document should be opened in word and when the users edits and saves the document, it should be saved in the customer workspace (without prompting for a path).

I know that Content Types would be a possiblity for this, but this is too complicated for our intention.

Is there a possiblity influence word on opening where the document should be saved? Like an Parameter in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Au contraire, document types are the only way you will be able to get out of this mess unscathed.

For each "template" you can create a "site content type". 
You will be able to set the url for that content type to the "template document" in your main site.

Customer site document libraries will then be able to create a "new" document and it will default to the library where they click the data from.
See
[Change a content type for a list or library](http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/sharepoint-server-help/change-a-content-type-for-a-list-or-library-HA010173454.aspx#BM1)